# Bash script for power AC plugin

Tags: command-line, bash, sound, scripts, sh

I'm working on a bash script that runs in an infinite 1 second loop, where if it detects that the computer is plugged into AC power, it plays the file `plugin.ogg` with `ogg123`, and if it is not plugged in, it plays a silent file `Silence.ogg`. However, I have a few issues. First, it seems to no longer loop (probably a side effect of the `wait` I had to throw in in order to avoid a looping charger input sound after the first detection. Secondly, it doesn't seem to want to change to the `/` directory and it therefore (I'm not sure if due to the `/` error or something else) can't find the files to play. Please help fix this, thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash
"cd /"

while true
do
    if on_ac_power; then 
        "ogg123 plugin.ogg"               ## Laptop on power
    else
        "ogg123 Silence.ogg"          ## Laptop on battery
    fi
    sleep 10                       ## wait 10 sec before repeating
done
```

Terminal output if run while computer is unplugged:
    `/home/brenden_mcfarling_live/Desktop/ac0.sh: line 3: cd /: No such 
    file or directory`

`/home/brenden_mcfarling_live/Desktop/ac0.sh: line 10: ogg123 
    Silence.ogg: command not found`

Terminal output when run while plugged in:
`/home/brenden_mcfarling_live/Desktop/ac0.sh: line 3: cd /: No such file or directory`

`/home/brenden_mcfarling_live/Desktop/ac0.sh: line 8: ogg123 plugin.ogg: command not found`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

At first: Why are you changing directory to root / ? Are your files located there ?

Remove the qoutes ".." from your command. So that it looks like

> ogg123 plugin.ogg

Make sure that you have installed the package `vorbis-tools`

> # sudo apt-get install vorbis-tools

Comment: My files are there. However, I'm still getting issues with them, so I'm going to place a local copy in the home directory, then into etc/skel (for each new user)

Comment: Now, I get the output of "Cannot open (name).ogg"

Answer (score 0):

As [@JonnyTischbein said](https://askubuntu.com/a/994413/504066): remove the quotes from your commands because else the shell will try to execute the literal command `"cd /"`, i.e. it will search for an executable file called `"cd /"` and execute it. Of course, it does not exist and you get `bash: cd /: No such file or directory`.

The same goes for `"ogg123 plugin.ogg"`. It will try to execute the file `"ogg123 plugin.ogg"` which also doesn't exist. Given your other error messages I assume that the *.ogg files reside in `/home/brenden_mcfarling_live/Desktop` (and not in `/`). Thus, after changing to `/` the files cannot be found any more and you need to supply the full path.

Put together:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /

while true
do
    if on_ac_power; then 
        ## Laptop on power
        ogg123 /home/brenden_mcfarling_live/Desktop/plugin.ogg
    else
        ## Laptop on battery
        ogg123 /home/brenden_mcfarling_live/Desktop/Silence.ogg
    fi
    ## wait 10 sec before repeating
    sleep 10
done
```

If the path-to or filename-of the sound files contained spaces, then you can use quotes *but only around the filename*:

```
ogg123 "/home/brenden_mcfarling_live/Desk Top/Very silent sound.ogg"
```

---

You may also want to have a look at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/227918/251553) (and its answer) at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com). There they say how to immediately catch the event of plugging/unplugging the AC adapter so you don't need to *poll* every 10 seconds but get triggered instead.

I admit, it's a bit complicated at first sight but the idea is:

- Do an *educated guess* what events happen when the cord is plugged in and out
- Write a script that gets called for "plugged in" (that plays your first sound file)
- Write a script that gets called for "plugged out" (that plays your second sound file)
- Create two rules in a new file below `/etc/udev/rules.d` that say *"when plugged in, then run script1.sh"* and *"when unplugged, then run script2.sh"*